# Can't reset checked radio value to defaut value ( Vue js)

Tags: vue.js

By default, I use local pickup option, with value 1. When user changes to free delivery, there will be some condition: if zip codes are valid, then it will changed to free delivery, if not, alert message will be displayed and local pickup will be checked again. The problem is that, I can set a default delivery value to 1 if zipcode is not suitable. But radio displays checked option as 2.

```
<label v-for="(del, index) in delivery" :key="index">
    <input type="radio" name="del" :value="del.value" v-model="defaultDelivery" @change="changeDelivery(del.value)">{{ del.label }}
</label>


export default {
    data () {
        return {
            delivery: [
                {value: 1, label: 'Local pickup'},
                {value: 2, label: 'Free Delivery'}
            ],
            accepted_zips: [
              12345,
              12346
            ],
            defaultDelivery: 1,
            zip_code: 78745
        }
    },
    changeDelivery: function(val) {
        if(val == 2 && !this.accepted_zips.includes(this.zip_code))
        {
            this.defaultDelivery = 1 //it should set 1 as checked again! But it is not aplied
            alert('Sorry but currently we don't cover your area.')
        }
    },
```

Comment: where is `fields` defined?

Comment: @Psidom, my mistake. I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the apostrophe in "don't" is closing your string, and you didn't put your method in a `methods` section. Correcting for that, your code works fine for me.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      delivery: [{
          value: 1,
          label: 'Local pickup'
        },
        {
          value: 2,
          label: 'Free Delivery'
        }
      ],
      accepted_zips: [
        12345,
        12346
      ],
      defaultDelivery: 1,
      zip_code: 78745
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeDelivery(val) {
      if (val == 2 && !this.accepted_zips.includes(+this.zip_code)) {
        this.defaultDelivery = 1 //it should set 1 as checked again! But it is not aplied
        alert('Sorry but currently we don\'t cover your area.')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>ZIP code <input v-model="zip_code"></div>
  <label v-for="(del, index) in delivery" :key="index">
    <input type="radio" name="del" :value="del.value" v-model="defaultDelivery" @change="changeDelivery(del.value)">{{ del.label }}
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I think there's something more to the problem.  While this works in the snippet, it doesn't work in a scaffolded project without `$nextTick`.  See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwpw7wp63).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/12rkm7f3/ it works :) but it doesnt work on my vue project :)

Comment: @Rashad you need to put `changeDelivery` in `methods: { }`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I had to do that, too. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ejLz7uf1/ it works as I told. I updated my fiddle. but it doesnt work on prod site :)

Comment: production site: https://order.tacisbeyti.com/checkout
You wil able to set free delivery, after warning message. I have no idea, what is going on

Comment: @Rashad try this `if(...) { this.$nextTick(() => { this.defaultDelivery = 1; }); }`